# I make Graph embedding using Gensim Doc2vec and then binary classification with 2 layers deep neural network in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, gensim, doc2vec

after making the graph embedding with Doc2vec, I want to make classification with keras, do I have to make embedding layer and put it as input to neural network or I directly use the embedding and split it into training and testing? also did the embedding layer improves the accuracy of neural network or not